# Iteration to create new list

Tags: python

```
day_of_week = []
for i in range(len(data2)):
    if data2["funded date"][i][0:3] == "Sun":
        day_of_week[i] = 1
    elif data2["funded date"][i][0:3] == "Mon":
        day_of_week[i] = 2
    elif data2["funded date"][i][0:3] == "Tue":
        day_of_week[i] = 3
    elif data2["funded date"][i][0:3] == "Wed":
        day_of_week[i] = 4
    elif data2["funded date"][i][0:3] == "Thu":
        day_of_week[i] = 5
    elif data2["funded date"][i][0:3] == "Fri":
        day_of_week[i] = 6
    else:
        day_of_week[i] = 7

print(day_of_week)
```

---

Cannot determine how to create a new list that will give an integer value for the day of the week.

Comment: Can you be a little more elaborate and explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you show an example of **exactly** what is in `data2` beforehand and **exactly** what `day_of_week` should end up as, as a result? Also: did something go wrong when you tried this code? What happened, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary of days then use list comprehension to create the day list

```
days = {d:i+1 for i,d in enumerate(['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'])}

day_of_week = [days[data2["funded date"][i][0:3]] for i in range(len(data2))]
```